# python sample from a scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have a scipy sparse matrix as for example:

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy import sparse
X = sparse.csr_matrix(np.random.randint(0, 10, (100, 10)))
```

I need to add `K` rows to this matrix. Each column of these new rows should be obtained sampling from the same column in the original matrix.

So for example.  The desired result should be something like:

`Z = np.concat(X, X_sampled, axis=0)`
where `X_sampled[:,i] = np.random.choice(X[:,i], k)`

How can I do that without moving to a dense matrix?

EDIT: An example with dense array

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                              
import scipy as sp                                                                                                                                                                                              

k = 20                                                                                                                                                                                                          
X = np.random.randint(0, 10, (100, 10))                                                                                                                                                                         
X2 =  np.zeros(shape=(k, X.shape[1]))                                                                                                                                                                           

for col_id in range(X.shape[1]):                                                                                                                                                                                
    X2[:, col_id] = np.random.choice(X[:, col_id], k)                                                                                                                                                           
res = np.concatenate([X, X2])
```

Comment: Probably a combination of multiplication and addition like such `sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((X.shape[0],1)))*X[i,:]+X`

Comment: no sorry I do not understand. Can you write it in an answer if you think it works

Comment: I thought you wanted to add, but it looks like appending is what you are trying to do. Sorry for the confusion. What you need is `sparse.hstack` I suppose. This is delivered with `scipy.sparse`

Comment: yes the problem is how to sample from a sparse matrix one column at the time

Comment: Try something along these lines `X[np.random.sample(X.shape[0], k, replace=False), :]`

Comment: Construct a new sparse matrix with the desired values, and join them with `sparse.vstack`.

Comment: It might help if you constructed an example of what  you want using dense arrays.  Then we can be sure that an sparse equivalents are right.  Currently your `X` sample is pretty dense.

Comment: I have added an example with dense array